# Difficulty using SPSS Statistics on MAC

Tags: macos, spss

Since I updated my Mac to Catalina, every time I try to open SPSS Statistics 26 Faculty Pack, it crashes and shows the following error.

I already reinstalled it and also tried SPSS 25 or 27.
In addition, my internet search did not help me.
So maybe someone has faced the same problem.

```
Process:               spssLauncher [69926]
Path:                  /Applications/IBM/*/SPSSStatistics.app/Contents/MacOS/spssLauncher
Identifier:            com.ibm.SPSS.Statistics.26.0.0.0
Version:               26.0.0.0 (26.0.0.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           spssLauncher [69926]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-07-12 18:09:59.924 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.5 (19F101)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.5 (17P5300)
Anonymous UUID:        D73BE916-44B3-7DB7-27DB-ED6B6CBB2D58

Sleep/Wake UUID:       CE6FBECC-D6EF-4B50-89E9-A443527A34A8

Time Awake Since Boot: 750000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1800 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        3

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007f00312d3935
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x7f00312d3935:
    Stack                  000070000ef5f000-000070000efe1000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 37
--> 
    MALLOC_TINY            00007f9376400000-00007f9376500000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening SPSS Statistics 26 Faculty Pack on Mac Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866961/opening-spss-statistics-26-faculty-pack-on-mac-catalina)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is also no answer to my problem .

Comment: Have you tried contacting IBM SPSS Support? Can you post the full crash log (this one appears to be clipped at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely there were issues with IBM SPSS Statistics 25.0 when macOS 10.15 (Catalina) shipped, as it was already in the field before this OS change.  Similarly there were issues in the initial release of IBM SPSS Statistics 26.0 as Catalina and version 26.0 were released within a week of so of on another.

Please see
https://developer.ibm.com/predictiveanalytics/2019/10/08/spss-statistics-on-catalina-macos-10-15/?_ga=2.234214810.541667164.1604327861-699861288.1590164240

for a discussion of these issues and suggested remedies.

If you continue to have trouble, please do open a Support case via:
https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/redirecttoopencasepage

At that time it will be helpful to have the full crash log.  On your mac, open the "Applications -> Utilities -> Console.app".  Review the "Crash Reports" and "Diagnostic Reports" sections looking for files with "spssengine" or "SPSS Statistics" in their names.  Right click on these and select "Reveal in Finder".  This will allow you to move/copy these log files to a p[lace where you can then send them in with your Support case.